# Revert strikeThrough text to plain text after some operation is performed in TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, ipad

I am using this code to change color of label and set text as strike through:

```
sliderlabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 260, 310, 30)];

sliderlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Bold" size:14];
[sliderlabel setTag:112];
sliderlabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[sliderlabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

NSString *sliderlabeltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Change To: In-Progress (%d %%)",(int)slider.value];
[sliderlabel setText:sliderlabeltext afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    NSRange boldRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"In-Progress (%d %%)",(int)slider.value] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange strikeRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:sliderlabeltext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Bold" size:14];
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
    if (font) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:8/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:94/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor range:boldRange];//34-139-34
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:kTTTStrikeOutAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] range:strikeRange];
        CFRelease(font);
    }

    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
[self.view addSubview:sliderlabel];
[sliderlabel release];
```

Now I want it to be without strike through when I perform some operation like click on a button, passing `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` in `addAttribute:value:range` doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try resetting strikeRange to (0,0)

Comment: If all else fails create a demo project that you upload to Dropbox. You should try to answer questions to build up your points, since you could then offer a bounty and would for sure get attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this additions.

```
@implementation TTTAttributedLabel (Additions)

- (void)setStrikeThroughOn:(BOOL)isStrikeThrough {
    NSString* text = self.text;
    [self setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^        NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    NSRange strikeRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:kTTTStrikeOutAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isStrikeThrough] range:strikeRange];
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];

// must trigger redraw
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```